# Stream with openWrite not writing until it is closed

Tags: c#, stream, webclient, filestream, streamwriter

I have a stream writer that opens using a WebClient.OpenWrite call.  For this simplified case, assume that reader is reading a multiple of dataChunkSize.

```
using (Stream writer = myWebClient.OpenWrite(myURIString)
{
    using (FileStream reader = new FileStream(myFileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < reader.Length; i += dataChunkSize)
        {
            byte[] data = new byte[dataChunkSize];
            reader.Read(data, 0, dataChunkSize);
            writer.Write(data, 0, dataChunkSize);
        }

        reader.Close();
        reader.Dispose();
    }

    writer.Close();
    writer.Dispose();
}
```

My data is the size of 2 dataChunkSizes.  However, it does not send any data (no data is received) until the writer.Close() call is called, where it only sends the first dataChunkSize worth of data...the second dataChunkSize of data is never sent.

How can I get it to send after every Write call?  I tried adding writer.Flush() but this did not help.

Thanks.

Comment: Probably not related to your question, but the way you are using your stream objects makes calling Close() and Dispose() explicitly redundant. They will automatically do so when the "using" block exits...

Comment: hi John, all the answers below seem to be in regards to buffer. Your real question still remains unanswered - how can you get each buffer to be sent independently? Did you find an answer, because calling Flush() doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your issue is because your last chunk is perhaps not the full length you expect (dataChunkSize). Also, I would add Flush to force each write there and then if needed (thou I am not sure if the flush will work). Try changing you for loop contents to this...

```
byte[] data = new byte[dataChunkSize];
int bytesRead = reader.Read(data, 0, dataChunkSize);
writer.Write(data, 0, bytesRead);
writer.Flush();
```

Comment: I tried adding this code...bytesRead in my test case is equal to dataChunkSize, and the flush does not help to send the data.

Comment: @John, bytesRead is the same in all loops? If you are not getting the write data across then you need to debug your end point. Find out what bytes are being received and compare them to what you are sending (or expecting to send)

Comment: bytesRead is the int counter of bytes being read...so I am always sending the same number of bytes, not necessarily the same data...I want to hit my endpoint with dataChunkSize bytes, but the buffer is messing things up and not sending every Write cycle

Comment: no, bytes read will be less if the final chunk of your read stream data is not the same length as your dataChunkSize. This is used to ensure that you do not write any trailing unwanted data to your write stream. It is definitely something you need to include even if it does not fix your issue. Do you have access to where you are writing the data? if so, make a simple file with a few words and then see what gets output at the other end. Oh. and you don't need to close and dispose with the "using" function - it will do this for you

Answer (score 0):

I guess the write is buffered. It won't write until the buffer is full or the writer is closed.

Comment: Is there a way to reduce the buffer size so that it is dataChunkSize?

Comment: Try to use the .Flush() method to flush. You can also use the StreamWriter class and set the AutoFlush property to True.

Answer (score 0):

WebClient may use inner buffered stream (network etc.).

And about the reader. It can read less.
So better use

```
    int amountRead = reader.Read(data, 0, dataChunkSize);
    writer.Write(data, 0, amountRead); 
    i += amountRead;
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to call the stream.Flush() method if you want to write before closing